# matching values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Say, I have dataset

```
mydat=structure(list(x1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), x2 = structure(1:5, .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x1", "x2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

x1 has values a,b,c,d
x2 has values a,b,c,d,e
```

how can  I display the values that there is in x2 var, but there is not in x1?
In our case this is `e`-value

as output I desire

```
    Value
1   e
```

If this question is duplicate, please let me know, I'll delete it.

Comment: `with(mydat, x2[!(x2 %in% x1)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
setdiff(mydat$x2,mydat$x1)
[1] "e"
```